# Json Response get single fields (Appwrite)

Tags: flutter, dart, appwrite

Currently I'm using Appwrite (a self hosted db).
When I want to read data with this code:

```
Future result = database.listDocuments(collectionId: "60be22axxxxxx");

          result.then((response) {
            print(response);
          }).catchError((error) {});
```

... I get the the following Json response:

```
{"sum":2,"documents":[{"$id":"60bf87c9a9726","$collection":"60be22a7c4a95","$permissions":{"read":["*"],"write":["*"]},"title":"test"},{"$id":"60bf95c0af7af","$collection":"60be22a7c4a95","$permissions":{"read":["*"],"write":["*"]},"title":"tes","desc":"des"}]}
```

How can I get single fields like the `title` from a db document and save that to a string or better, to an object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this,

```
String data = jsonDecode(response);
Print(["documents"][0]["title"]);
```

the [0] is the first for 2 you can get the second with [1], or deploy a boucle.

Comment: thanks for your answer, meanwhile I got the exact same solution.